# To assign javascript value to a php variable in the same page

Tags: php

I have a page with php and javascript. In the php section i need to call a function with an argument $arg, Now $arg is the problem, $arg is actually value of a dropdown option in the same page . Here is what i am trying to accomplish.

```
 <?php include("aclass.php")?>
<script language="javascript">
function getoption(val){
}
</script>
<html>
 <select name="sel" onchange="getoption();">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>   
</html>
<?php 
$object=new a;
$object->calculate($arg);
 ?>
```

// Here the issue is $arg should be the value i select in dropdown, $arg should be 1 if i select One and should be 2 if i select Two in dropdown.

" Is  there a possibility to pass the javascript value 'val' to php variable $arg "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you want to do is not possible without a form submission or without a contact to the server. PHP is a server side language whereas javascript is client side. So obviously you cannot do a server function in the client side.

So, either make this as a form and submit the form on change of the value in select or if you dont want reload of the page, try using ajax

Comment: In your case, dont submit the form. onchange of the value use ajax to call `abc.php/?select=value`, then in the php get the value and use it to in the function like `$object->calculate($_GET['select'])`, echo the required value here and this data will be returned by the ajax call function. Use this to make changes in the present page

Comment: @look4php: This [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) would be a good place to start learning about ajax

Comment: I will look in w3 schools thanks,But you mean i have to call the function in abc.php page ? @Balanivash

Comment: ya.. You can load an page using ajax, calling the functions must be done in the page only.

Comment: in abc.php i can, $val=$_GET['SELECTEDVALUE']; if(!empty($val)){    echo $object->calculate($_GET['select'])  }     This can be done right @Balanivash   So that now i am able to call the function with the required argument

Comment: yes. In abc.php => `<?php $value =$object->calculate($_GET['select']);echo $value; ?>` So, the echoed data will be the return value of the ajax call. So, you need to read the return data and display it in the required palce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP variables in Javascript but the opposite can't be done. PHP runs server-side. Javascript is client-side. The only way to send something from Javascript to PHP is using AJAX. You might want to search in that direction.

Comment: ok by using ajax i could get that value in ajax page and also display it in this page, but can we assign that value to a variable in this page @Oltarus

Comment: No, because when the page is loaded, there are no more PHP variables @look4php in it. The PHP "program" ends when the page is sent to the browser. You can do it by reloading the page, maybe. But acting on the same page is impossible.

Comment: @look4php: ajax is just calling a url asynchronously, getting the results and changing a part of the page without requiring to reload the full page. So, wht you should do is, on change of the value is the select, call the url with the select value, and in the php page, get the value using `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: or i just have to call the function in the Ajax page right? @Balanivash